# Add CKeditor to javascript file

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, append, ckeditor

```
  $(container).append('<label for="input">'+
                '<h3> <i class="fas fa-arrow-right"></i> Add Body</h3>'+
                '</label><textarea name="contentBody" rows="8" cols="80" placeholder="Go Ahead..."></textarea>'

              );
```

How can I add ckeditor to this textbox?

Comment: add this in your script on same page CKEDITOR.replace('contentBody')

Comment: Add that but its not working

Comment: can we add something at js file

Comment: You can put it in a js file but you want a link to the js file where you want the ckeditor

Comment: How can i link it in js file

Comment: <script src="myproject/js/script.js"></script>